# SecurityException on grantUriPermissions()

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I have an app, that can open txt files from file manager, edit them and save changes to that file.

Thing is, when **uri scheme** is `file://` everything works fine. But if **uri scheme** is `content://` I get an exception when trying to `grantUriPermissions()`.

Here is how I try to save file:

```
    OutputStream os;
try {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
        context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
    os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    writer.write(newText.trim());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    context.revokeUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.fileexplorer.provider.FileExplorerFileProvider uri content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/txtpad/uu.txt from pid=32456, uid=10208 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

My `<provider/>` in AndroidManifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I have this in my activity tag in AndroidManifest

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: How *exactly* are you getting this `Uri`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, i added more info. Basically I'm opening file using intent.action.VIEW and then getIntent().getUri()

Comment: Just set `android:exported="true"` in your provider

Comment: Is the code where `context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);` appears (from your first code snippet) being invoked from the activity associated with that `<intent-filter>`? Or is that code being invoked from another component (a separate activity, a service, etc.)?

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, it is being invoked from activity associated with `<intent-filter>`. Well, this line of code is in another class in method named *saveFile()* that is called in activity with `<intent-filter>`

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting rid of some of your code, leaving you with:

```
OutputStream os;
try {
    os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    writer.write(newText.trim());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code that I deleted was related to granting *other apps* rights to the content identified by the `Uri`. You are not doing anything with other apps, and the `revokeUriPermission()` bit in particular might be screwing up your own app's access to the content.

Then, completely uninstall and reinstall your app, and see if things start working.

If not, make certain that either:

- You only use this `Uri` in the activity where you got it (via `getIntent().getData()`), or
- If you pass the `Uri` to another component, add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent` that you use to start that component (and perhaps `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, depending on what that other component needs)